Automatically Run A Script
Is there a way in Google sheet to automatically run/call an existing macro/script when a cell value change?
For example, in Cell A1 I have a drop down list and I want to automatically call/run my existing macro/script every time I change Cell A1. I don't have a problem with my existing macro but I just want to automatically run/call it every time I change the value in my drop down list which is Cell A1.
Name of the existing macro/script: HideRowsEqualTo1Only()
function HideRowsEqualTo1Only() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == 1) { // Assuming the values you want to check are in the first column
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1); // Rows are indexed starting from 1
    } else {
      sheet.showRows(i + 1); // Unhide rows not equal to 1
    }
  }
}



You can use a trigger to run an event whenever a cell is edited. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

In your situation and your script, I think that the simple trigger of OnEdit can be used. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
Please add the function onEdit as follows. When you use this script, please change the dropdown list of cell "A1". By this, onEdit function is automatically run by the simple trigger.
function HideRowsEqualTo1Only() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == 1) { // Assuming the values you want to check are in the first column
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1); // Rows are indexed starting from 1
    } else {
      sheet.showRows(i + 1); // Unhide rows not equal to 1
    }
  }
}

// Added this function.
function onEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  if (range.rowStart != 1 || range.columnStart != 1) return;
  HideRowsEqualTo1Only();
}


In this modification, when the cell "A1" is edited, your function HideRowsEqualTo1Only is run.

If you want to run the script at the specific sheet, you can also use the following onEdit function.
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1"]; // Please set your sheet names.
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (!sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || range.rowStart != 1 || range.columnStart != 1) return;
  HideRowsEqualTo1Only();
}



Note:

If an error related to the authorization occurs, it might be required to change the simple trigger to the installable trigger.

References:

Simple Triggers
Installable Triggers
Event Objects


Thank you it worked. If I want to change the Cell A1 to Cell A3, I'll just change the numbers below right?
  const { range } = e;
  if (range.rowStart != 3 || range.columnStart != 1) return;
  HideRowsEqualTo1Only();
}


@Poch Thank you for replying. From Thank you it worked., I understood that your issue was resolved. About your additional question If I want to change the Cell A1 to Cell A3, I'll just change the numbers below right? function onEdit(e) { const { range } = e; if (range.rowStart != 3 || range.columnStart != 1) return; HideRowsEqualTo1Only(); }, it's yes.

@Poch For example, if you want to directly use the A1Notation, please modify if (range.rowStart != 1 || range.columnStart != 1) return; to if (range.getA1Notation() != "A3") return;. By this, only when the edited cell is "A3", HideRowsEqualTo1Only() is run.

@Poch By the way, from Thank you it worked, when your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer
